# How can I print a chessboard using javascript to look like the following grid

Tags: javascript

The chessboard must look like this:

```
---------------
|R|N|B|Q|K|B|N|
---------------
| | | |P| | | |
---------------
```

I have tried making an array of arrays to print the letters but it didn't work.

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: Please be spesific about what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

```js
let board = [
  ['R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N'],
  [' ', ' ', ' ', 'P', ' ', ' ', ' ']
]

let result = '---------------\n'

for (let i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
  result += '|'
  for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; ++j) {
    result += board[i][j] + '|'
  }
  result += '\n---------------\n'
}

console.log(result)
```